Man Has Secret Family, Keeps one wife secluded in woods
I saw part of a movie on American television in the early to mid nineties which has eluded me ever since.  Unfortunately this was at a time when "channel guides" didn't exist:  One would have to open a periodical called "TV Guide" and flip through pages to find what was on.  I did not have a TV Guide at the time.
Anyway, the movie appeared to be somewhat current for the time and may have been a made-for-tv movie.  The only parts I saw had no on-screen vehicles so it is hard to say for sure when it was produced.
As for the plot of the movie, from what i could deduce, a man had two families, neither of which was aware of the other.   However, the wife/girlfriend with whom he had no children, was kept secret in a house in the woods.  He would come visit her for a little while but would then leave on a "business trip."  She becomes suspicious that there is a second woman and she decides to kill him.
Now, from what I watched, she is not going to just kill him, she wants confirmation of her suspicions.  So when he comes home for a visit, she has rigged various traps to kill him as soon as he admits his infidelity.  He is aware that she is suspicious and becomes very wary of every action of his and hers.  He decides not to drink from a carton of milk which he thinks might be poisoned, he avoids certain areas of the small house he keeps her in for fear of being trapped.  At one point while they are talking about her suspicions, they sit at the kitchen table.  Under the table where she is sitting there is a handgun/crossbow (that detail is fuzzy) attached and she has her finger on the trigger.  However he convinces her that she has fabricated the other family in her mind.  So she lets go of the trigger.  He eventually leaves and walks off through the forest.
What happens after that, I am hoping to find out.  This is the point where I had to turn off the TV and leave the house.  The last couple of decades worth of research has led me nowhere.
Other details:
the woman was blonde
the man was brunette
the house was very small, one could call it a cabin or cottage
I may have watched it on Bravo when they still concentrated on the arts, so its possible it was foreign, but i don't remember any accents or "non-american english" idioms or terminology. (a flashlight was called a flashlight)
I REALLY hope someone recognizes this as I want to know what happens.  Its been a 20 year cliff-hanger!!!
